# How to view all the default HHVM options and settings?

Tags: hhvm

In this question at [HHVM poor performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17898783/hhvm-poor-performance) it mentions changing the JitWarmupRequests value for HHVM. But is there a command or way to see all default set values for all HHVM options ?

Similar to how mysql server can see all set values via **mysqladmin variables** command ?

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, but I found a recently updated  listing of all HHVM php.ini settings (and default values): http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/ini.php  (not the easiest reference--firehose of info)

Answer (score 4):

No there is no way to do this in HHVM. I'm working on it, but nothing yet.

Comment: thanks Paul.. definitely would be a useful tool as that's how I usually learn all the ins and outs setting wise for new software - see what's default and lookup the manual/docs to see what each setting does :)